# Applying loop on vlookup to gather data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, vlookup

So basically, I have a table, where in Column A, I have a repeated list of data with multiple duplicates. In Column B, I have different sets of data related to column A, and then same as Column C. What I wish to have excel do for me is to give me the table (A15:C18), where the Column A data is one cell for each value, and then all the related information is shown right next to it in a concatenated manner.

[image]

**My approach so far**

So basically, what I have done so far is the following approach:

1. Since Column A are the only thing common in defining the different
   lines, so I came up with a way to define each line as a unique line,
   using the following =(A1&"--"&countif($A$1:A1;A1). This formula then
   helps me identify each row as A--1, A--2, A--3, B--1, B--2 and so
   on. Hence I have numbered each data in each row, in a way.
2. Since I want a unique list, therefore using VBA I get a unique list of variables in a new sheet. Hence, I get the list of just A, B and C in a column instead of them being duplicates.
3. Once I have the unique list, I then use the =countif() function to count how many times, the variable shows up in the original list (Column A). Like for example, A shows up three times, hence I know that I need to extract 3 rows for this specific data point.
4. Then using that information, I then proceed to use the =vlookup() function, using the equation =VLOOKUP(A&"--"&1;TABLE;COLUMN)&", "&VLOOKUP(A&"--"&2;TABLE;COLUMN)&", "&VLOOKUP(A&"--"&3;TABLE;COLUMN) .... so on depending on how many times the variable is in the list.
5. Finally, for example, I then write the vlookup code, and I can then extract all the cells into one place.

**PROBLEMS and HELP**

So the above approach I have described works on a pilot scale with lots of manual changes for different data points. The problems are the following:

1. The process of using =vlookup() is based on the =countif() function. I wrote down a very long formula using IF statements saying that =IF(COUNTIF()=1;VLOOKUP(VAR&--&1;TABLE..);IF(COUNTIF()=2;VLOOKUP(VAR&--&1;TABLE..)&","&VLOOKUP(VAR&--&2;TABLE..); ...

Basically, I wrote the IF statement depending on the value of the countIf value. If it is 1, then extract the values for --1, but if it is 2, then do it for --1 and --2, and vice versa. But this is such a bad approach because I can not write this equation for 100 duplicates and if a data point shows up more than 100 Times, then this approach is useless. **hence, I would like to know, if it is somehow possible to use a loop VBA code for excel to do a vlookup? So if countif is 4, then do a vlookup from --1 until --4 and so on?**

2. Another limtation is that even though B shows up 2 times in column A, but it only has 1 data point in Column B, and that is the information I need. Hence I should be focusing on that instead of using the =countif() on Column A. **Any suggestions on how I can count, how much information is infront of a data point in the second column? The data in Columns B and C are unique so there are no duplicates. **

I am stuck with the above two points, which kind of makes up the engine of the workbook. So any help or suggestion on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the updated image to show the general approach:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem, here's my approach.

Pre-requisites:
You need Microsoft Scripting Runtime: Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime -> check the box

There are 2 components of this code.
First the sub you will run:

```
Sub Concatenate_Data()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourWorksheetsName")
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim r As Long
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim letterStr As String
    
    For r = 2 To lastRow
        letterStr = ws.Cells(r, 1).Value
    
        If dict.Exists(letterStr) Then
            If Not ws.Cells(r, 2).Value = "" Then
                dict(letterStr).Candy = dict(letterStr).Candy & ", " & ws.Cells(r, 2).Value
            End If
            If Not ws.Cells(r, 3).Value = "" Then
                dict(letterStr).Juice = dict(letterStr).Juice & ", " & ws.Cells(r, 3).Value
            End If
        Else
            dict.Add letterStr, New Letter
            If Not ws.Cells(r, 2).Value = "" Then
                dict(letterStr).Candy = ws.Cells(r, 2).Value
            End If
            If Not ws.Cells(r, 3).Value = "" Then
                dict(letterStr).Juice = ws.Cells(r, 3).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    Dim k As Variant
    r = 2
    For Each k In dict.Keys
        ws.Cells(r, 5).Value = k
        ws.Cells(r, 6).Value = dict(k).Candy
        ws.Cells(r, 7).Value = dict(k).Juice
        r = r + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Next is the Class (it is named Letter):

```
Public Candy As String
Public Juice As String
```

Here is the input and output I get:
[image]

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you so very much! But I tried running your VBA code and it gives me an error at "New Letter" saying that "User-defined type not defined"? Any idea how I can work around it?

Comment: did you create a class named Letter?